# Retirar uma letra do alfabeto com FOR

Tags: php

Olá preciso remover uma letra apenas do alfabeto com FOR.

Estou percorrendo o alfabeto de A a Z, porém preciso tirar a letra Y

```
<?php
for($letra = ord("A"); $letra <= ord('Z'); $letra++)
{
   echo chr($letra).",";
}
?>
```

Resultado esperado:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Z,
```

Mas até agora não consegui tirar ficando

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar uma `if` simples para isto e também pode usar o `implode` para se concatenar, faça isto:

```
<?php
$todasLetras = array();

//Salvar o valor em uma variavel pode melhorar um pouco a performance
$final   = ord('Z');
for($letra = ord('A'); $letra <= $final; $letra++)
{
    $current = chr($letra);
    if ($current !== 'Y') {
        $todasLetras[] = $current;
    }
}

echo implode(',', $todasLetras);
```

Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/nCVno7

Comment: Funcionou, certinho!

Answer (score 7):

Uma coisa interessante é que o php usa a mesma convenção do [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) para strings isso significa que você consegue incrementar o valor uma string baseado no valor [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) desde que ele seja válido(65..90 A..Z, 97..122 a..z), logo é possível resolver esse problema de outra forma, sem o uso das funções [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) e [chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).

Pode usar a abordagem de criar um array com as letras do alfabeto com [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), depois obter a chave que contem o `Y` (chave 24) com [array_seach()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) basta remove-la com [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) seja com variável `$item_remover` ou com o índice direto 24.

use o [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) para formatar o array como uma string.

```
<?php

$alfabeto = range('A', 'Z');
$item_remover = array_search('Y', $alfabeto);
unset($alfabeto[$item_remover]);

echo implode(', ', $alfabeto);
```

[Exemplo - ideonline](http://ideone.com/ziO9qP)

[php manual - operador de incremento](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Answer (score 1):

Numa abordagem diferente, uma proposta simplificada e otimizada:

```
<?php
$remove = 'y'; 
$str = 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z';
echo str_ireplace(array(','.$remove, $remove.','),'',$str);
?>
```

Ok, qual o motivo de modificar o código original completamente?

O código original começa com redundâncias:

```
for($letra = ord("A"); $letra <= ord('Z'); $letra++)
```

Consumirá menos processos se escrever o alfabeto inteiro numa string.

Como o resultado final será as letras do alfabeto separados por vírgula, com exceção da letra a ser removida, então não faz sentido usar um laço de repetição para gerar a string.