# Qual é o nome do operador => no PHP usado em arrays?

Tags: php, operadores

No PHP, quando vamos declarar um `array` diretamente, temos o operador `=>`.

Sei que no PHP temos o `->`, que é *object separator*, porém precisei dar o nome para `=>` e não soube explicar.

Qual é o nome dele?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A **flecha dupla** (`=>`) segundo o manual serve para atribuir um valor a uma chave especifica na definição um *array* e também para separar chave de um valor em um `foreach`, como citado pelo Maniero.

> For arrays, assigning a value to a named key is performed using the "=>" **operator**. The precedence of this operator is the same as other assignment operators.

Fonte: [Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

Na página de [precedências dos operadores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) é possível ver essa linha, note o último elemento da segunda coluna.

```
Associativity |Operators                                       |Additional Information
right         |  = += -= *= **= /= .= %= &= |= ^= <<= >>= =>   |assignment
```

Com relação ao nome do simbolo `=>` na documentação do PHP parece não existir nenhum nome especifico, o mais próximo do formal seria T_DOUBLE_ARROW (conforme apontado nos comentários), que aparece em erros de sintaxe.

Informalmente é conhecido como [fat comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma), termo que provavelmente veio  do [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) linguagem da qual o PHP herdou [algumas características](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70378/91).

Comment: Será que tem relação com o tal do `T_DOUBLE_ARROW`?

Comment: É o próprio. `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` é o nome pelo qual o parser reconhece essa seta.

Comment: Já tinha vista o termo `fat comma` em um livro, vou procurar a referência depois.

Answer (score 10):

Não é um operador, ao contrário da crença popular e erro na Wikipedia, pelo menos para o PHP. A linguagem possui [esses operadores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). É apenas um elemento de construção da linguagem que separa a chave do valor de *arrays* associativos. Podemos chamá-lo de pontual, como é o `;`. É algo que é usado para dar fluidez ao texto do código.

Comment: Deixou então mais uma questão em aberto: Então como é denominado esses "elementos de construção"? Tokens?

Comment: Token é qualquer elemento de construção da linguagem. Não sei se dá para dizer que são sinônimos, acho que sim, mas não garanto. Não sei se podemos chamar este elemento específico de alguma coisa mais específica que *token*, que é genérico demais. Talvez chamar de separador de *arrays* associativos. Que eu tenha achado, não tem nada na documentação sobre isto. Oficialmente parece que a linguagem não dá nome algum. mas eu ficaria com o nome `double arrow` é o mais próximo de algo oficial. Não confio no artigo sem referências da Wikipedia.

Comment: Ainda estou procurando alguma referência oficial, o mais próximo que achei foi a [documentação do perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) de quem o php herdou bastante coisa. É só uma evidência, nada oficial.