# Para que servem os operadores php ->, => e ::?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Para que servem os operadores:

- `->` (menos com maior que)
- `=>` (igual com maior que)
- `::` (dois pontos duplos)

E qual a diferença entre cada um.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77062/qual-%C3%A9-o-nome-do-operador-no-php-usado-em-arrays

Comment: Também tem essa dup: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77062/101

Comment: Não acho que esteja duplicada porque queria saber a diferença entre os tres operadores e não achei essa pergunta aqui.

Comment: E sabendo cada um, você não vai saber a diferença? Pondo em outras palavras, se você sabe o que é o Silvio Santos, um asteróide e um caminhão, ainda assim precisa de alguma explicação da diferença entre eles? Sugeriria ler os artigos, aí se ainda não entender, pode deixar comentário que a gente ajuda.

Comment: Ok
Muito obrigado

Comment: Só pra ficar claro, não é uma "crítica" à sua pergunta, é que se ficar aberta, o que vai surgir aqui é repetição do que está nas outras. A idéia é que você saia com o conhecimento necessário, de qualquer forma. A duvida é justa, simplesmente estamos tentando apontar pra solução que já tem pronta. Note que tem o comentário do @bigown com um complemento que faltou ao fechar, que é o link para o post da flecha dupla `=>`. Mas qualquer dúvida, comente mesmo.