# Repetir o alfabeto semelhante as colunas do excel

Tags: php, algoritmo

Estou criando uma função que me retorna o alfabeto em um array conforme o tamanho de colunas passadas.

A principio estava fazendo somente um loop usando o **range("A", "Z");** mas quando tive mais de 26 colunas já não me atendeu mais, com isso, procurando na internet, o que achei foi uma sugestão aqui http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/532733-repetir-o-alfabeto-varias-vezes-como-as-colunas-do-excel/ dada pela resposta do Willian Bruno, mas que também não está muito correto, pelo menos não funcionou aqui, dai usando como base criei a minha só que também não me retorna o esperado, que seria o alfabeto (a-z, aa-zz, aaa-zzz), semelhante as colunas do excel.

segue o que estou fazendo.

```
function alphaRepeat($columnsSize = 10)
{
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

    $abc = range("A", "Z");
    $abcSize = count($abc);

    $alpha = array();

    while ($i < $columnsSize) {

        if (((int)($i / $abcSize) - $j) > 0) {
            $j++;
        }

        $item = '';

        if ($j > 0) {
            $item.= str_repeat($abc[$j - 1], $j);
        }
        $item.= $abc[$i - ($abcSize * $j)];

        $alpha[] = $item;

        $i++;
    }

    return $alpha;
}
```

Comment: Se o `$columnSize` for 5 ele deve ir de `a` até `e`? se for 27 de `a` ate `aa`?

Comment: isso, se for de 1 até 52 entao tem que ser de `a` até `az`. se for de 1 até 53 entao tem que ser de `a` até  53 `ba` e por ai vai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível incrementar uma string pelo seu valor ASCII no php desde que ela esteja no interva válido de (65..90 A..Z, 97..122 a..z) por isso `range('A', 'Z') funciona, aqui tem [explicação mais detalhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70378/91).

Pode criar uma função para encapsular esse código, `$maximo` é número informado pelo usuário, `$inicial` pode ser `a` ou `A`

[Exemplo ideone](https://ideone.com/AgTnGA)

```
<?php

$inicial = 'a';

$maximo = 27;
$atual = 0;

$colunas = array();
while($maximo > $atual){
    $colunas[] = $inicial++;
    $atual++;
}
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
    [7] => h
    [8] => i
    [9] => j
    [10] => k
    [11] => l
    [12] => m
    [13] => n
    [14] => o
    [15] => p
    [16] => q
    [17] => r
    [18] => s
    [19] => t
    [20] => u
    [21] => v
    [22] => w
    [23] => x
    [24] => y
    [25] => z
    [26] => aa
)
```

Comment: nao entendi como isso que passou gerou essa saida, nao esta faltando nada?

Comment: @MarceloDiniz, você diz o `print_r($colunas)` ?

Comment: nossa, eu fiquei aqui tentando entender sem ter tentado rodar e não tinha entendido como fazendo o acumulador do `$inicial++` já vai passando as letras corretas, mas agora já vi. Valew

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma fórmula onde você passa o número da coluna, e recebe a string correspondente. Pode ser usada para se obter qualquer coluna, sem necessidade de calcular as anteriores.

É um complemento interessante à resposta do @rray, caso se necessite fazer várias operações em colunas não consecutivas, como um update de planilha, ou conversão de coordenadas internas para coordenadas para exibição na tela (imagine mostrar uma *view* parcial de uma planilha, ou uma fórmula com referências internas).

```
function CabecalhoPlanilha( $numero ) {
    $string = '';
    while( $numero ) {
        $string = chr( 65 /* 97 para minusculas */ + ( --$numero % 26 ) ) . $string;
        $numero = (int) ( $numero / 26 );
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Demo no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/HG3H2R)**

Answer (score 2):

Também dá pra fazer assim:

```
for ($a = 'a';  $a != 'aaa'; $a++) {
    $colunas[] = $a;
}
```

Isso vai gerar um `array` com uma sequência de `a` até `zz`.

Se precisar definir um limite, poderá ser feito assim:

```
function create_cell_range($limit) {

     for ($a = 'a', $current = 0; $current < $limit; $a++,$current++) 
     {
          $columns[] = $a;
     }

    return $columns;
}


var_dump(create_cell_range(3)); //array(3){'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Se você estiver utilizando versões do PHP superior a `5.5`, não recomendo utilizar `array`. Nesse caso, é melhor utilizar um `Generator`.

Assim:

```
 function create_cell_range($limit) {

     for ($a = 'a', $current = 0; $current < $limit; $a++,$current++) 
     {
          yield $current => $a;
     }

}
```

Daí quando precisar, é  necessário apenas utilizar no `foreach`.

Assim:

```
foreach(create_cell_range(27) as $key => $value) {
     echo "$key => $value";
}
```

Os generators porem representar uma economia absurda de memória, já que ele não cria um item para cada elemento de um `array`, e sim retorna sequencialmente um item quando necessário.

Comment: Ficou legal também :D

Comment: @rray, já viu esse for com dois parâmetros?

Comment: Ainda não, o mais estranho que lembro foi um `/=` lol divisão.

Comment: @rray, incrementei na resposta a utilização de `yield`, Generators

Answer (score 0):

Também da pra fazer assim :

```
function numberToColumnName($number){
    $abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $abc_len = strlen($abc);

    $result = "";
    $tmp = $number;

    while($number > $abc_len) {
        $remainder = $number % $abc_len;
        $result = $abc[$remainder-1].$result;
        $number = floor($number / $abc_len);
    }
    return $abc[$number-1].$result;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++){
    echo numberToColumnName($i)."\n";
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/pHr0BD)